# Ajax call failing in rails when calling controller method

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a scenario where a `<div>` tag is refreshed using ajax whenever a user clicks on row of table. But due to some issue, it is always getting `"alert(fail)"` message. 
When i replace view file with just `"HI"` text, it works.. but when having below mentioned form, it shows fail alert. Please help.

### .JS file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tab tr').click(function(){
        var val= $(this).attr('id');
        alert(val);
    $.ajax({
           url: "/users/profile/",
           type: "GET",
           data: {'id': val},
           success: function(response){
              $(".tab").html(response) 
            },
           error: function(response) {
                        alert('fail');
                      },
});

   });
    });
```

### My controller method :

```
def profile 
@prof = User.where(:id => params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
format.html {}
end
```

### Method's view:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@prof, :html => {:class => 'form-vertical'}) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>
<%= f.first_name %>
<%end%>
```

Comment: what happens when you try format.js instead of format.html?

Comment: its still coming the same way ..i tried it by `$(".tab").html(response)` and in controller method .. respond_to do |format|
format.html {} format.js{}
end

Comment: Please look into log and if you can't solve problem by yourself post it here.

Comment: hi michael .. i have tried for long by myself. As i could not figure out so i have posted it here

Comment: Anything in the logs?

Comment: What happens if you replace User.where(:id => params[:id]) with User.find(params[:id]) ?

Comment: Hi @GergoErdosi your answer helped. Can you please explain why it worked.

Comment: @RahulInsane Good to hear that! Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `where` method in the following code returns an array:

```
@prof = User.where(:id => params[:id])
```

However in your view, you are referring to a single item:

```
<%= f.first_name %>
```

Replace the `where` method in the controller with `find`, which returns a single item:

```
@prof = User.find(params[:id])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your url should be as

```
url: "/users/profile"
```

not

```
url: "/users/profile/"
```